# Angular testing router in Jasmine with jasmine then()

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

In .ts i have:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>
  this.router.navigate([LangParams.activeLang, 'login'], {
    queryParams: { returnUrl: returnUrl },
  })
);
```

and test

```
it('should navigate to /login', inject(
  [AuthStore, AuthenticationService, Router],
  (
    authStore: AuthStore,
    authService: AuthenticationService,
    router: Router
  ) => {
    spyOn(authService, 'logout');
    const routerSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl').and.returnValue(
      Promise.resolve(true)
    );

    authStore.logout();

    expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/', { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
));
```

How i may test navigate() in then()?

Comment: You're already returning a promise, so what happens if you add the second expectation? Also: why *does* it navigate twice?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't currently appear to have *attempted* to test it; did you? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  If add  `expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([LangParams.activeLang, 'login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: ''}});` 

Have a message `Expected spy navigateByUrl to have been called with [ [ 'ru', 'login' ], Object({ queryParams: Object({ returnUrl: '' }) }) ] but actual calls were [ '/', Object({ skipLocationChange: true }) ].`

Comment: Hi @Сергей...did you find the solutions?